# How to use Android Material Stepper library for form validation in old Android Project but the UI is need to create by using Jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

1. I merged my old Android Kotlin project with jetpack compose.
2. I have tried different methods for using stepper library but it wont work.
3. I have also try adding this in my xml but it wont work. can anyone help.
4. and created a adapter for stepper also but it wont work

```
<androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView
        android:id="@+id/compose_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

  <com.stepstone.stepper.StepperLayout
            android:id="@+id/stepperLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="?actionBarSize"
            app:ms_backButtonColor="@color/app_primary_accent"
            app:ms_completeButtonColor="@color/app_primary_accent"
            app:ms_completeButtonText="Submit"
            app:ms_nextButtonColor="@color/app_primary_accent"
            app:ms_stepperType="dots" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. i have created it using the fragments.
   Add this in your your activity where you want to add stepper.
   (test_activity.xml)

```
<com.stepstone.stepper.StepperLayout
            android:id="@+id/stepperLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="?actionBarSize"
            app:ms_backButtonColor="@color/app_primary_accent"
            app:ms_completeButtonColor="@color/app_primary_accent"
            app:ms_completeButtonText="Submit"
            app:ms_nextButtonColor="@color/app_primary_accent"
            app:ms_stepperType="dots" />
```

2. add below lines in your activity TestActivity.kt

```
class TestActivity : AppCompatActivity(), StepperLayout.StepperListener {
    private lateinit var stepperLayout: StepperLayout

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
        setContentView(R.layout.test_activity)

        stepperLayout = findViewById(R.id.stepperLayout)
        stepperLayout.adapter = StepperAdapter(supportFragmentManager, this)
        stepperLayout.setListener(this)
        actionBarToolbar?.post { supportActionBar?.subtitle = "Page 1" }// custom action bar
    }
    override fun onCompleted(completeButton: View?) {
       var intent= Intent(this,TestActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
        finish()
    }
    override fun onError(verificationError: VerificationError?) {
    }
    override fun onStepSelected(newStepPosition: Int) {
        val subTitle = when (newStepPosition) {
            0 -> "Page 1"
            1 -> "Page 2"
            2 -> "Page 3"
            else -> ""
        }
        supportActionBar?.subtitle = subTitle
    }
    override fun onReturn() {
        finish()
    }
}
```

3. create a adapter for stepper

```
class StepperAdapter(fm: FragmentManager?, context: Context?) :
    AbstractFragmentStepAdapter(fm!!, context!!) {

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return 8
    }

    override fun createStep(position: Int): Step {
        return when (position) {
            0 -> Page1.newInstance()
            1 -> Page2.newInstance()
            2 -> Page3.newInstance()
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported position: $position")
        }
    }
}
```

4. create fragments for each page

```
class Page1 : Fragment(), Step {
    companion object {
        fun newInstance() = Page1()
    }
    @ExperimentalComposeUiApi
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        return ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
            setContent {
                JFLtestTheme {
                    Page1JetCompose()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    }
    override fun verifyStep(): VerificationError? {
        val message = validateInitData()
        return null
    }
    override fun onSelected() {}
    override fun onError(error: VerificationError) {
        ShowDialog.showSnackbar(view, error.errorMessage)
    }
}
```

5. now create jetcompose file and add your layout

```
@Composable
fun Page1Jetcompose() {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val emailState = remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }
    val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current

    Column {
        TextField(
            modifier = Modifier
                .focusRequester(focusRequester)
                .fillMaxWidth(),
            value = emailState.value,
            onValueChange = {
                emailState.value = it
            },
        )
        Button(onClick = {
            focusManager.clearFocus()
            if (emailState.value.isEmpty() ) {
                focusRequester.requestFocus()
                Toast.makeText(context, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }) { Text(text = "Button")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Because I wanted the view to be written entirely with Jetpack Compose, I made a Material Stepper library.

1. Add **jitpack** in your `build.gradle`

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

2. Add **[Material Stepper Compose](https://github.com/Xsims/compose-material-stepper)** library to your `app/build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
     ...
     implementation "com.github.Xsims:compose-material-stepper:0.2.0"
}
```

3. Create a `Stepper` with `Step`s in a composable function

```
@Composable
fun MyStepper() {
    Stepper(
        steps = List(8) { index ->
            Step(
                title = "Name of step ${index + 1}",
                subtitle = "Subtitle of step ${index + 1}"
            ) {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .height(250.dp)
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .background(color = Color.Black)
                )
            }
        }
    )
}
```

4. You can customize `Step` to manage state

```
val state = mutableStateOf(StepState.TODO)
lateinit var currentStep: MutableState<Int>

val steps = listOf(Step(
    title = "My state Step",
    state = state,
) {
    when (state.value) {
        StepState.TODO -> Button(onClick = {
            state.value = LOADING
            CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch { delay(2000) }
                .invokeOnCompletion { state.value = ERROR }
        }) {
            Text("CLICK")
        }

        LOADING -> CircularProgressIndicator()

        ERROR -> Button(onClick = {
            state.value = COMPLETE
            nextStep()
        }) {
            Text("RETRY")
        }

        COMPLETE -> Text("Complete")
    }
}, Step(title = "My second step") {
    Text("Second step")
}, Step(title = "My third step") {
    Text("Third step")
},
)

fun nextStep() {
    if (currentStep.value < steps.size)
        currentStep.value = currentStep.value + 1
}

@Composable
fun MyStepper() {
    currentStep = remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    Stepper(
        currentStep = currentStep,
        steps = steps
    )
}
```

[image: demo of material stepper library with different state]

Comment: Failed to resolve: com.github.Xsims:compose-material-stepper:0.2.0